# QtWebKit not displaying css/xsl

Tags: c++, xml, stylesheet, xslt, qwebkit

I cannot get qtwebkit to display css/xsl.  I have tried both and they work in web browsers, but not in the qtwebkit.  Is there a setting I need to enable to apply a stylesheet, or is this a downfall of the qtwebkit?

***EDIT: XSLT support is disabled in Qt 4.7 (http://gitorious.org/webkit/qtwebkit/commit/8961d12)***

XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="status.xsl"?>
    <hk>
    <item><name>Some Parameter</name><value>value</value></item>
    <item><name>Test Count</name><value>38</value></item>
    </hk>
```

xsl (status.xsl)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="*|/">
    <html><head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"></meta></head>
    <body> <h2>Status</h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>Parameter</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="hk/item"> <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="value"/></td>
    </tr> </xsl:for-each> </table>

    </body> </html> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>
```

QtWebKit

```
     webView->settings()->setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile("file.css"));
     webView->load(QUrl("http://192.x.x.x:port/file.xml));
```

When viewing the URL in a browser the css looks fine... but not in webkit?

Comment: @JonnyCplusplus: What is the meaning of "I cannot get qtwebkit to display css/xsl"? Is it not honoring your `xml-stylesheet` PI?

Comment: @Alejandro: the text is being displayed in the webkit, but not the stylesheet.  In a webrower, it is a table with colors and formatting in the webkit, straight text... just a line of all the data from the xml...

Comment: @JonnyCplusplus: You need to post reduce input sample, complete stylesheet and desired output in order to answer.

Comment: How do I mark this answered... I answered my own question!

Comment: @JonnyCplusplus: Just do not answer in question but in its own answer.